# Передать src в img jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Не могу понять как прередать src img в другой блок с картинкой, в консоль лог выводится src. А в src вставляется [Object Object]

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title> </head> <body>
        <div class="img-wr">
            <img src="a.png" alt="">
            <a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">получить</a class="st">
        </div>
        <div class="img-wr">
            <img src="b.png" alt="">
            <a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">получить</a>
        </div>
        <div class="img-wr">
            <img src="3.jpeg" alt="">
            <a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">получить</a>
        </div>
        <div class="img-wr">
            <img src="4.jpg" alt="">
            <a class="st" href = "javascript:void(0);">получить</a>
        </div>
        <div class="sn">
            <img class="re" src="" alt="">
        </div>
        <script
                  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
                  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
                  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- <script src="sc.js"></script> -->
        <!-- <script src="script.js"></script> -->
        <script src="sm.js"></script> </body> </html>
```

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.st').click(function () {
        let imgr = $(this).closest('.img-wr').find('img').attr('src');
        $('.re').attr('src', $(imgr));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дак вы сами в объект оборачиваете `$(img)`, уберите `$()` и просто передайте `img`:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.st').click(function () {
          let img = $(this).prev().attr('src');
          $('.re').attr('src', img);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title> 
   </head> 
   <body>
        <div class="img-wr">
            <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/VOLKI-krasivye-i-ochen-umnye-zhivotnye.jpg" alt="">
            <a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">получить</a class="st">
        </div>
        <div class="img-wr">
            <img src="https://www.meme-arsenal.com/memes/50569ac974c29121ff9075e45a334942.jpg" alt="">
            <a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">получить</a>
        </div>
        <div class="sn">
            <img class="re" src="" alt="">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```